# No Camera found dialog when accessing Capacitor Camera Web Application on mobile

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, browser, camera, capacitor

my goal is to access a web page, which uses the capacitor camera plugin, witha mobile device in order to take and upload photos.

I followed this tutorial on how to code a website with the camera functionality:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app

The web page is working but by accessing it with a mobile device (tried with IOS and Android) it shows this dialog:

[image: no_camera_found_dialog]

If you click "Choose image" there will be functionality meaning **it is possible to take photos or upload them.**

*Is there any way I can prevent the "No Camera Found" dialog or change the style of this dialog?*

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have Camera permission?

Comment: I dont ask for the Camera permission on the website. I will look into that, thank you very much!

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thank you very much, your answer solved my problem